# Dúvida em LINGUAGEM C

Tags: c

Galera, boa noite.
Estou aprendendo C na faculdade e nos foi pedido um exercício para ler o salário de um funcionário.(até peço perdão pq perto dos mais experientes, meu código deve estar um lixo, mas tamo ai né...)
(O proprietário desta empresa determinou um reajuste salarial de 7,5% a todos os seus funcionários. Além disto, concedeu um abono de R$ 150,00 para aqueles que recebem até e, inclusive R$ 1750,00. Dado o valor do salário líquido de um funcionário, informar o salário final do colaborador.)
Eu *consegui* montar o código no devC++ MAS ele não está lendo o IF e o ELSE. Alguém consegue me ajudar ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() 
{
    int ra;
    char nome[50], empresa[40];
    float sal_hoje, sal_total, sal_reajuste;
    printf("Ola, seja bem vindo a Boxbacon \n");
    printf("Digite o seu nome completo : \n");
    scanf("%s",&nome);
    printf("Digite o seu RA : \n " );
    scanf("%d", &ra);
    printf("Digite o seu salario : \n ");
    scanf("%f", &sal_hoje);
        if(sal_hoje <= 1750)
            {
                sal_reajuste=sal_hoje * (0,075);
                sal_hoje= sal_hoje + 150 + sal_reajuste;
                sal_total=sal_hoje;
                printf("tera um salario total de : , "sal_total);
            }
        else 
            {
                sal_reajuste=sal_hoje * (0,075);
                sal_total=sal_reajuste + sal_hoje;
                printf("tera um salario total de : " sal_total);
            }
    
    return(0);
```

}

O que aparece é só isso
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tipo, ele não retorna o salário corrigido em nenhuma das hipóteses e eu gostaria de entender o que está errado.

Answer (score 0):

O seu código caso não estivesse lendo os If e Elses, não imprimiria o

- *tera um salario total de :*

Logo, o erro do código está nesta mesma frase, você não colocou o %f para a impressão do float, mas declarou a variável. E um outro erro no seu código é não colocar virgula depois da frase no printf, o correto seria:

```
 printf("tera um salario total de: %f",sal_total);
```

E um outro "erro", seria a utilização da virgula ao invés do ponto, no *0.075*

Código plenamente corrigido:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int ra;
    char nome[50], empresa[40];
    float sal_hoje, sal_total, sal_reajuste;
    printf("Ola, seja bem vindo a Boxbacon \n");
    printf("Digite o seu nome completo : \n");
    scanf("%s",&nome);
    printf("Digite o seu RA : \n " );
    scanf("%d", &ra);
    printf("Digite o seu salario : \n ");
    scanf("%f", &sal_hoje);
        if(sal_hoje <= 1750)
            {
                sal_reajuste=sal_hoje * (0.075);
                sal_hoje= sal_hoje + 150 + sal_reajuste;
                sal_total=sal_hoje;
               printf("tera um salario total de: %f",sal_total);
            }
        else
            {
                sal_reajuste=sal_hoje * (0.075);
                sal_total=sal_reajuste + sal_hoje;
                printf("tera um salario total de: %f",sal_total);
            }

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, tem isso ai também.
Corrigi aqui, mas testando novamente ele para no mesmo lugar. Ele não le o salario total
Muito estranho

Comment: De fato havia mais um erro, corrigi e enviei o código completo

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente nao precisa pedir para o usuario inserir o nome  da empresa, nem o R.A e o nome completo.

Primeiro: Você vai criar um nome fictício, o R.A tem que ser o seu e o nome completo tambem.

Segundo: Não vejo necessidade de usar `#include <stdlib.h>` mas, use `#include <locale.h> setlocale (LC_ALL, "Portuguese");` para acentos se preferir.

As variáveis do `float` estão corretas. Acredito que você deveria criar nomes mais sugestivos para elas se preferir. Já as demais não há necessarias ter.

Seguindo o que voce ja fez segui uma ideia para resolução.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
int main(){
setlocale (LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
float sal_hoje, sal_total, sal_reajuste;

printf("\nDigite o seu salario : \n ");
    scanf("%f", &sal_hoje);

        if(sal_hoje <= 1750)
            {
                sal_reajuste=sal_hoje * (0.075);
                sal_total= sal_hoje + 150 + sal_reajuste;               
             
            }
        else
            {
                sal_reajuste=sal_hoje * (0.075);
                sal_total=sal_reajuste + sal_hoje;
                
            } //obs: Nessa parte voce vai colocar a impressão das informações: sal_hoje,sal_total, sal_reajuste.

  printf(" \nO salario liquido é %2.f",sal_hoje );
obs: Os demais printf segui a mesma sequencia.
}
```